# Python Fabric NameError: global name 'log_action' is not defined

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to use the Fabric "log_action" method as documented here:

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments

However it appear that the ""log_action" method has not been implemented.

Fabric 1.8.2, Paramiko 1.12.3

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.api import sudo
from fabric.api import sudo, warn_only

def new_user(username, admin='no', comment="No comment provided"):
log_action("New User (%s): %s" % (username, comment))
pass

NameError: global name 'log_action' is not defined
```

Comment: log_action is not a fabric or built-in Python function. Where are you expecting it to come from?

Comment: Arr - I thought it was a function provided by Fabric, since it was in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Andrew Wilkinsons's comment.

There is a bit of confusion in the documentation. [The chapter](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.6/usage/fab.html#per-task-arguments) is actually about passing arguments to fabric tasks, `log_action` call is not relevant and it is not a real function - it's just an example what you can possibly do inside the task.

Comment: @user1513388: even if fabric did define `log_action`; you would get the same error because you haven't imported it e.g., `run("true")` would  produce the same error if you remove `from fabric.api import run` from the code.